# Cannot enable the ML Engine APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm following Tensorflow tutorial

[Quick Start: Distributed Training on the Oxford-IIIT Pets Dataset on Google Cloud](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md)

At the step 3 "Enable the ML Engine APIs", I'm facing the following problem:

"Enabling API" box never disappears and I'm stuck on this page.

[Endless Enabling API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3n71.png)​

**Question:**

Why the problem occurred and how can I solve it?

Comment: I don't know the exact amount of time you have to wait but it could as long as 5-10 minutes. Have you waited that long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a project from Console first and then go to ML Engine via dashboard, you'll see a more descriptive explanation regarding what's going on (you have to wait up to 10 minutes).

Not sure that the same applies when you follow the step 3 link: I recall waiting more than 10 mins a few times.

[Enabling API message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbmH7.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot I can see that a project hasn't been selected. You need to select a project from the dropdown menu at the top of the screen, where it says 'Select a project'.

[image]

If you haven’t got a project yet then you need to [create one](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects).

Comment: The project has been selected. It's name is Tutorial project.

Comment: I've updated the answer to make sure it's clear which dropdown menu I'm referring to